How should I install a GFCI outlet when the current outlet has two hot wires and one neutral?
I am replacing an outlet in my kitchen with a GFCI outlet. This should the second to last outlet on the branch, so I was expecting to see two sets of wires in the box. Instead, I saw this:


There are 3 sets of wires in the box: one coming from the bottom (A), and two from the top (B and C). The setup is:

A's hot wire goes directly to the outlet
B's hot wire goes directly to the outlet
A's neutral wire goes into a pigtail
Neutral wire connects the pigtail to the outlet
Both B and C's neutral wires go into the pigtail
B's red wire and C's hot wire are tied together

How should I wire up the GFCI with this configuration? Is it possible/safe to do so?
My current assumption is the bottom wire (A) is the LINE. After confirming that is the case, my plan is to

Connect A's hot wire to the LINE of the GFCI
Disconnect A's neutral wire from the pigtail and instead connect it to the LINE of the GFCI
Connect B's hot wire to the LOAD of the GFCI
Connect the neutral pigtail to the LOAD of the GFCI

Would that be correct?

On the side of the outlet that has the two black wires has the jumper between the screws been removed? (Compare it to the side with the white wire that still has the jumper in place.) If the jumper is removed then you have either a half-switched outlet or an outlet fed from both sides of a multi-wire branch circuit (MWBC). (Or an outlet fed from two circuits not in a MWBC, which would be bad.) If the jumper is intact then one black wire is incoming hot and the other is outbound.

The jumper is there. I determined that this is likely a MWBC, with power coming from B. Does this mean I cannot use one GFCI to protect the this outlet and the final downstream outlet? How should I configure my outlets to protect this outlet and one coming off of it?

If you read the GFCI instructions, it will describe a way to put 2 wires under any screw.  This is informally called "screw-and-clamp".  Tighten Very Hard.
The above is the answer to your question. The rest is background.
Every GFCI has a warning sticker covering 2 secret terminals.  The sticker says "DO NOT USE. FOR WIZARDS ONLY." or words to that effect.  Follow those instructions even if the GFCI paper instructions suggest otherwise.
This is to employ a feature that every GFCI has called "Downline Protection".  This allows them to protect additional outlets same as the sockets (if any) on the GFCI itself.  It's a neat trick to save money - 1 GFCI per circuit instead of 1 GFCI per receptacle - but it has significant drawbacks, e.g. a plain socket randomly goes dead, you have no idea why and call an electrician to fix it. He shows you a GFCI 3 rooms over that tripped!  In fact, downline protection is so full of land-mines and costly annoyances that "For Wizards Only" is good advice.
Your wiring is not suitable for using downline protection, so you can't use it and you leave the warning tape on the Load terminals.

So what you are saying is that, given this is a MWBC, screw both hot wires from B into the LINE hot and connect the neutral from the pigtail to the LINE neutral? Then install a second GFCI on the downstream receptacle?

Yeah. That's what you have to do to put GFCI on MWBCs. (unless you want a $100+ GFCI breaker, probably not worth it).
